# How to use size of in __align__ for cache alignment, while using GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, memory-alignment

I have two structs.

```
t_struct_inner {
  int a;
  ... // a lot more members
}

t_struct_outer {
  t_struct_inner[1000] inners;
  t_struct_outer* next;
}
```

I malloc `t_struct_outer` in my code. I want `t_struct_inner` to be cache aligned. 
My solution is to use

```
 __attribute__((aligned(
       ((sizeof(t_struct_inner)/CACHE_LINE_SIZE)+1) * CACHE_LINE_SIZE
)))
```

But obviously I cannot do this as I cannot use `sizeof` here. I do not want to hardcode a value for `aligned`.
Any ideas how I can achieve the above?

Comment: *I cannot do this as I cannot use sizeof here* why are you saying you cannot use `sizeof` here?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this do the trick?

```
struct __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE))) t_struct_inner {
  int a;
  ... // more members.
};
```

Edit: Suppose your cache line is 128 bytes long and t_struct_inner's members have a total size of 259 bytes long. Due to the alignment of 128 bytes the following array:

```
t_struct_inner my_array[2];
```

is (3*128)*2 bytes long. the attribute(aligned) forces every element of the array to be aligned to an 128-byte boundary.

Comment: The CACHE_LINE_SIZE is smaller than the t_struct_innter. I need it to align to multiple of the cache line size.

Comment: @sheki Why? Is it not already cache aligned when you do it like in this answer?

Comment: Suppose the cache line size is 128 bytes. and the t_inner_struct is of size 259bytes then it has to be aligned as `aligned(3*128)`

Comment: @sheki Why does it need to be aligned at a multiple of the cache line size? What benefit does that provide?

Comment: If a thread is accessing a struct. It can just get stuff out of the cacheline. If a struct is shared b/w cachelines the Thread might have to wait as another thread is accessing the cacheline.

Comment: @sheki You assumption that it needs to be aligned to multiples of the cache line is wrong. Caches have an associativity far bigger than one nowadays, which takes care of the problem you are imaging

Comment: Added some more information to my answer, since I still think it does all that is required.

Comment: @GuntherPiez Can you elaborate on your statement regarding to the cache? AFAIK, caches nowadays is still behave akin to what sheki said, that is, a cache line (of private CPU cache) would need to do cache coherence to get the latest content filled by another CPU core.

Comment: My point is, isn't it recommended to do such cache line alignment to prevent false-sharing of cache line?

Comment: @Feng.Ma Assuming by "false sharing" you mean two different address locations with the same tag are cached at the same location in the cache, and so, would continiously trash each other if accessed. This is can (and usually is) be prevented by adding associativity to the cache. This problem can occur with one or multiple cores or threads and has nothing to do with private caches and/or cache coherency

Comment: If you talk about multiple threads accessing the same location, cache coherency (usually transparent for the software) is required anyway, and all caches will have the same alignment or misalignment anyway. The alignment will help in using as less as possible cache lines though, or avoid splitting the struct at a cache line.